# How to show cache only if the device is offline in Volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I am using Volley and I want to cache response(no server control-cache headers).

I want to show the cached value only if there is no internet.

What I tried:

```
private Entry getCachedEntry(NetworkResponse response) {
    // entry that will be passed to the response instance
    Entry cachedEntryForRequest = HttpHeaderParser
            .parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response);

    // The request queue cache
    Cache cache = BaseApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue()
            .getCache();

    // gets the cached entry for the request
    Entry cachedItems = cache.get(GetEvents.KEY_CACHE);

    if (NetworkChecker.isOnline(mContext)) {

        // puts the entry with the new data to the cache
        cache.put(GetEvents.KEY_CACHE, cachedEntryForRequest);

        // return null so the new data to be shown
        cachedEntryForRequest = null;
    } else {
        // show the cached data if the device is offline
        if (cachedItems != null) {
            cachedEntryForRequest.data = cachedItems.data;
        } else {
            cachedEntryForRequest = null;
        }
    }

    return cachedEntryForRequest;
}

    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        Log.v(TAG, "response: " + json);

        Object fromJson = mGson.fromJson(json, mType);

        return Response.success((T) fromJson, getCacheEntry(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

This is my own solution but I'm doing something wrong because it's showing the cache result even if the device is online?!?!?

Comment: hey, did you get a solution to this?

Comment: ammm Yes... but I'm too busy to post the answer :) I will do it later :)

Comment: No worries, i have found the answer myself. Thanks

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal can you share the solution you found.

Comment: please post the answer to this question .